# Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binder AMQP(S)

Tags: solace

I would like to connect my Spring Boot application to a Solace PubSub+ instance using the following URL `amqps://localhost:5671`. I would like to use Spring Cloud Stream and Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binder for that.

I tried the following configuration in my `application.yml`:

```yaml
solace:
  java:
    host: amqps://localhost:5671
    clientUsername: admin
    clientPassword: admin
```

But this does not work. I keep getting errors that `amqps` is not a valid scheme. Same goes for plain `amqp://` URIs.

I have dug a little deeper into the code of Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binder, and I am not sure this is actually possible at all. It seems the configuration above only works for `tcp://` and `tcps://` URIs, both resulting in messages being sent over Solace's proprietary SMF protocol.

This works:

```yaml
solace:
  java:
    host: tcp://localhost:55555
    clientUsername: admin
    clientPassword: admin
```

... but does not use AMQP but SMF.

How can I configure Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binder to communicate via AMQP and AMQPS?

Comment: @Mrc0113 I hope you could help here.

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Cloud Stream binders from Solace do not support AMQP. They are written using the Solace Java API JCSMP and use SMF, which you have observed.

I am not sure if there is a community SCS binder using AMQP 1.0. Is there a reason you need it to work in AMQP 1.0?

Comment: This is correct. The Solace binder communicates only over SMF as it uses the JCSMP APIso your SCSt app would connect to the broker over SMF. That said, keep in mind that Solace Brokers automatically provide protocol translation so you would still be able to have your SCSt apps communicate with applications using other protocols like AMQP or MQTT